# Setting watch on element inside ng-if

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Let's say I have following view:

```
<div ng-if='some === "something"'>
   <input type="text" ng-model="foo.Bar"/>
</div>
```

In controller `some` is set:

```
foo.controller('fooFoo',
   function fooFoo($scope) {
      $scope.some = "something";
      $scope.$watch('foo.Bar',function (nVal, oVal) { etc...});
   }
);
```

Provided the input is inside a div with `ng-if` the `watch` doesn't work.

Why? Can I somehow make it work?

Comment: where is `foo` on your scope?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must create empty object of foo inside controller.

```
foo.controller('fooFoo',
   function fooFoo($scope) {
      $scope.foo = {};
      $scope.some = "something";
      $scope.$watch('foo.Bar',function (nVal, oVal) { etc...});
   }
);
```

---

**recommended:** you can use **ng-change** instead of $scope.$watch(); because $watch is a bad practice for angular app performance.

using ng-change (HTML):

```
<div ng-if='some === "something"'>
   <input type="text" ng-model="foo.Bar" ng-change="onChange()"/>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
foo.controller('fooFoo',
   function fooFoo($scope) {
      $scope.some = "something";

      $scope.onChange = function(){
          console.log($scope.foo.Bar);
     };
   }
);
```

Comment: To be honest I've omitted some details. Foo object is created on form loading, but in a callback function executed after retrieving some data from the server. It's still a little bit vague to me because if I don't use ng-if directive this solution works, but declaring object (here $scope.foo = {}) has helped. Thank you for pointing ng-change. I didn't know it's better or even exist, but it has one more advantage - when foo is undeclared it throws the exception while $watch doesn't. Thank you for your help Nasser.

Answer (score 2):

Use `ng-change` on `input` element instead of `$watch` in controller.

Answer (score 2):

I think problem is ng-if create its own scope. Then we have fooFoo scope (parent) and ng-if scope.

the property `foo.Bar` at first time (page init) is avaiable in both scope and point to the same place (foo.Bar property in fooFoo controller) because of inheritance. But after you change your input element (in ng-if scope), the `foo.Bar` in ng-if scope is pointed to its own scope property so `foo.Bar` in fooFoo controller is not getting changed.

If you use controllerAs i think it'll be resolved.

something like this:

```
<div ng-controller="fooFoo as ff">
    <div ng-if='ff.some === "something"'>
       <input type="text" ng-model="ff.foo.Bar"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

And you controller:

```
foo.controller('fooFoo',
   function fooFoo($scope) {
      var ff = this;
      ff.some = "something";
      $scope.$watch('ff.foo.Bar',function (nVal, oVal) { etc...});
   }
);
```